# Searching in a cell for a specific value

Tags: matlab

I have a cell of dimension 100x1 in matlab. I want to search this cell for a particular string so that it returns me the indexes where the value is that particular string. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

With [`strfind()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/strfind.html).
For example,

```
strfind({'aa','bb','cc'},'aa')
```

Comment: I am not talking about finding a string inside another string. My cell is of dimension 100x1. So, it consists of 100 strings in each row and I want to find the index of those rows which match that string

Comment: @rajansthapit: Yes, and `strfind` can deal with cell arrays of strings.

Comment: Can't we use find so that it returns an indices array with the indices of the elements with a match.